# Android, ожидание закрытия Activity

Tags: android-sdk, android

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при вызове нового Activity, она становится фоновой, но остальные  Activity продолжают работать. Есть ли способ остановить работающие Activity, пока работает вызванное в нем? Что-то вроде метода join из Java (я попытался так тормознуть работу Activity, вдруг бы прокатило, но нет...)?

Если это имеет значение, у меня работа приложения идет, как на фото и при вызове нового Activity нужно останавливать старое, дожидаясь ответа от него (обычно, вызванное Activity работает с базой данных или меняй переменную вызывающего Activity), а, в случае с Activity 2, после получения ответа от Activity 3, перезапускать его, при этом не продолжая работу 1.

Я никак не могу понять, с помощью чего можно так делать! Хоть создавать отдельный класс, а в нем потоки, отвечающие за каждое Activity (да, я любитель костылей :D)... Извиняюсь за кривую "не до" блок схему нарисованную в Paint.

[image: Работа приложения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте использовать

```
intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_1);
```

и получить ответ через `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // если пришло ОК
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      switch (requestCode) {
      case REQUEST_CODE_1:
        // тут выполните команду возврат от ActivityTwo
        break;
      case REQUEST_CODE_3:
        // просто пример
        break;
      }
    // если вернулось не ОК
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

пример [Подробнее про onActivityResult. Зачем нужны requestCode и resultCode](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/69-urok-30-podrobnee-pro-onactivityresult-zachem-nuzhny-requestcode-i-resultcode.html)